# Setting values of selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have checkboxe that will dynamically appear number of times based on my database. Each checkbox Id is generated dynamically. Where initial value of $i is 1.

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="<?php  echo $i - 1;?>" />
```

Now want to set value of each selected checkbox to 1 and 0 to all unselected checkbox in real time . Plz help me.

Comment: Since you are generating the checkboxes via PHP, why not use an if statement in PHP to set the checked state?

Comment: Yes it is better than my answer

Comment: @CM Kanode  How ??? Give sample code.

Comment: @CMKanode: That makes no sense, since the php code does not set the input's to checked, so that would be equivalent to just appending a 1 to all input-boxed. However, the question is not quite clear about what is needed.

Comment: @HerbertKruitbosch:  Okay, re-reading the question, you are correct.  The question wasn't quite clear to me.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: On selecting checkbox i want to set it's value to 1. On deselect it's value should change to 0 . If not selected then it's value should be 0 ....

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, to set values in real time you need to do the following:

```
$("[name='ch[]']").on("change", function() {
    this.value = +this.checked;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MMSFB/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to toggle the values of the checkboxes. I would suggest using jquery and something like this:

php:

```js
<input type="checkbox" class="toggleable" name="ch[]" id="<?php  echo $i - 1;?>" />;
```

javascript:

```js
$(".toggleable").each( function(i, elem) {
    elem.checked=!elem.checked;
});
```